# Rails Lambda ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, lambda

I am trying to implement a lambda within a `where()` method in an `ActiveRecord` on Rails. Here is my code:

```
 @applications.where { |app| !((calculate_days_ago(app.shipping_date) >= 10 && calculate_days_ago(:app.shipping_date) <= 19) || app.followup_calls.count == 0) }
```

Where `@applications` is an `ActiveRecord` (e.g. `Application.all`). But when I am trying to access it (e.g. `order`, `where`), it's type is change to `WhereChain` and I am having an exception:

> undefined method `where' for #ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x6fb1000>

Is there a way I can implement a lambda expression on my `where()` condition with the proper return type?

*Note:* I came from a C# background and such lambda can be done like that, I am a newbie on Ruby on Rails. I am not aware that this community bash newbies with downvotes. I tried my best to make my question as clear as possible.

Comment: How are you passing block to `#where` ? I never saw such in documentation. Link please

Comment: What is `@applications?`  Normally you would call `.where` on the class, eg `Application.where( ....`

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona you can pass a block to any method, but it is ignored unless the method calls the block.

Comment: @MaxWilliams `@applications` is an `ActiveRecord` like `Application.all`

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the info. I am a newbie in Rails (coming from a C# background). Is there a way to implement what I am trying to do though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` method doesn't take (or at least it won't use) any block passed to it. If you want to filter based on arbitrary ruby code, then use

```
@applications.select {|app| !((calculate_days_ago(app.shipping_date) >= 10 && calculate_days_ago(:app.shipping_date) <= 19) || app.followup_calls.count == 0) }
```

Be aware though that this fetches all the rows matching any previous conditions on the scope, creates active record objects from them and then filters them - if possibly it will in general be a lot faster to rewrite this to use `where` e.g.

```
@applications.where(:shipping_date => (19.days.ago .. 10.days.ago))
```

In addition this keeps things as a relation so you can continue to chain extra `where`, `order` etc. calls.

Comment: Thanks, but the `select` return an `Array` and I am unable to use `where` on it. Does your second example translate to "Shipping Date is between 10 to 19 days ago"?

Comment: @john It does indeed.

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know a way to implement my second condition (`app.followup_calls.count == 0`)?  I have a one-to-many relationship to the `followup_calls` table and I need to know if it has no followup-call?

Comment: @john either use a counter cache on the association (so that there is just an integer column you can filter on) or a left join. Lots of questions here about that specific type of query